# websocket rails javascript not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, websocket

I use websocket rails channel and trigger it from a sidekiq worker. the trigger get logged in the websocket-rails log correctly, like this, with a removed < before StationSongs:

> I [2014-12-31 16:19:28.788] [Channel] [station10938] #StationSongs _id: 54a41400446562680e17c102, name: "Fedde & Di-Rect Le Grand", title: "Dream Dance Vol.73 - 14 - Where We Belong", info: nil, week: 1, year: 2014, date: 2014-12-31 15:19:28 UTC, station_id: 10938>

It get triggered like this:

```
channel = "station" + station_id.to_s
WebsocketRails[:"#{channel}"].trigger(:new, stationsong)
```

I then set subscribe for the channel station10938, the javascritp code looks like this:

```
var dispatcher = new WebSocketRails('localhost/websocket');
var stationid = $('#songhistorylist').data("id"); // is 10938
var stationname = 'station' + String(stationid);
var channel = dispatcher.subscribe(stationname);
console.log(channel);
channel.bind('new', function (song) {
        console.log(song);
        console.log('a new song about ' + song.name + " - " + song.title + ' arrived!');
});
```

This will only print out channel, not anything else, even if the channel comes up in the log all the time.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having the same problem..

Answer (score 0):

On the line: `WebsocketRails[:"#{channel}"].trigger(:new, stationsong)`, remove the ":".

It should be: `WebsocketRails["station#{station_id}"].trigger(:new, stationsong)`
In your JS, your dispatcher should look like this: 
`var dispatcher = new WebSocketRails(window.location.host + '/websocket')` because your server port might change.

Your server should have (assuming `stationsong` is set correctly):

```
channel = "station" + station_id.to_s
WebsocketRails["#{channel}"].trigger(:new, stationsong)
```

Your client JS should have:

```
var dispatcher = new WebSocketRails(window.location.host + '/websocket')
var stationid = $('#songhistorylist').data("id"); // is 10938
var stationname = 'station' + String(stationid);
var channel = dispatcher.subscribe(stationname);
console.log(channel);
channel.bind('new', function (song) {
        console.log(song);
        console.log('a new song about ' + song.name + " - " + song.title + ' arrived!');
});
```